# I want to know why $rank \: M=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a non-zero and non-invertible $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose that $M$ is a non-zero $n \times n$ matrix such that $MA=AM=0$ . I want to know why $rank \: M=1$.

Comment: Is there no constraint on $A$'s rank?

Comment: @calle.text is Suppose that $A$ is non-invertible $n \times n$ matrix. there exist non-zero elements $X=(x_1 , \ldots,x_n)$ and $Y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ in $M_{n\times 1}$ such that $AX^t=0$ and $YA=0$.let $M=X^tY$. since there exist $i,j$, $1\leq i, j \leq n$ such that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are non-zero ,$M\neq 0$. on the other hand $AM=MA=o$ .since $rank\:M=1$, $nullity \:M=n-1$

Comment: That is quite different from the question you asked.

Comment: Unless $n=2$ this statement is false.

Answer (score 5):

i don't think it is true. here is a counterexample. $$AM = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} $$ but $rank(M) = 2.$